# The call of hawkers

Tags: idiomatic-language

How do peddlers or hawkers in English speaking regions draw the attention of the people in the street? I mean how do they make their calls? Is this the way?

> Here comes pen seller!
>
> Pens! Here you get good pens!
>
> Pens, pens... get good pens!

What is the way they use? Or is there any other way they make their calls to invite customers?

Comment: The 'Cries of London' were famous in earlier centuries: [here](https://tfl.gov.uk/forms/12393.aspx?ID=51) is an old verse representing some of them. The modern equivalent is probably the market trader calling out the price of a bunch of flowers or punnet of fruit.

Comment: @ Kate Buntin What sentence do they deliver?

Comment: Well, something like "Strawberries - pound a punnet" "Two bunches of daffodils for a pound" (I'm guessing at the prices) or anything they can think of to attract the attention of passers-by. There's no set formula.